# Using source control without having a host

Tags: svn, version-control

I will work with 2 developers on one application, and we want to use subversion control application to avoid conflicts.

I don't have a server with a static IP, is there anyway to setup a virtual host on my machine ans install the source control so that all the team can update the source code.

Thanks!

Comment: No need for a VM - just install the source control server on your machine.

Comment: How can the other developers access it?

Comment: well, through the local network? Of course, that will only work if your machine is on

Answer (score 1):

Just install the svn server on one of the pc:s. If you are running windows then get something like [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), and if you are running some Linux dist then just install it.

The other guys need to know you current ip, and then they can access the server when you are on the same lan.

But at the end of the day, if you don't have a fixed ip and a real server then it is probably easier to use a distributed system like git over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you can also consider using a distributed version control system, such as [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). This way, every user will have a local copy of the repository. More about DVCS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).

Comment: But how does Git synchronize the versions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but that means if your machine is unavailable then they're a bit stuck. If you're going to go down the route of doing it on your box you don't necessarily need to have a VM running, you can just install Subversion server onto it, set up a static IP address for your machine and run it like that. They check out from  and you check out from <127.0.0.1>.

Maybe look at git? It'll allow individual source control for if the main repo isn't available, and then they can push back to it your main repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared filesystem (see the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#nfs) for supported types) and create a file repo with `svnadmin`.

Comment: My experience on using file protocol for svn on a shared filesystem is simply horrible.  Please use file protocol for accessing local repository only